# Call to SQL Server from classic ASP and ADO will not keep disconnected recordset open

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I'm busy porting a classic ASP site. For a particular call to SQL Server 2012 via ODBC, I use the following code:

```
objRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
objRS.Open strSQL, objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic
```

Using SQL Server Profiler, I can see the call is being made and running the same query directly in SQL Server Management Studio returns my records.

I then continue with the following code:

```
Set objRS.ActiveConnection = Nothing
objConn.Close 
set objConn = Nothing
Set GetRecordSet = objRS 
set objRS = Nothing
```

where `GetRecordSet` is the name of the function.

In the calling page, where I set my recordset equal to `GetRecordSet`, I perform a check with `if not RS.EOF then` crashes with query cannot be performed on a closed recordset. It's supposed to be disconnected, but for some reason it is failing.

Update: Interestingly, the SQL being passed that fails is a stored proc. If I change the value being passed in as `select * from mytable` it works. On the db side the user that I'm using to connect to via ODBC has read/write and execute permissions on the Stored Proc.

Comment: It's existing code from the original site. I'm just trying to port as much of the code as is at the moment until a complete rewrite

Comment: Did you mean "if not GetRecordSet.EOF"?, because I don't see a variable called "RS" in your code and objRS is closed. aside from that, why not close the recordset and the connection after you use them? They get cleaned up anyway after the page finishes, and the open connection can be used to issue more queries if need be.

Comment: The above are just the important snippets. As already said all works fine on SQLServer 2005 on Windows Server 2003, it's only playing up with SQLServer 2012 on Windows 2012. I tried opening the recordset using `objRs.Open strSQL, objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText` and looking at the contents of objRS immediately on comeback and it still said in the immediate window that the object was closed.

Comment: @ErikOosterwaal RS is in the parent e.g. `Set RS = GetRecordset("myConnection",sql)`

Comment: I'm beginning to think it's the version of ADO that is linked with IIS on windows 2012 as you have to tell it to run in classic mode. However, I don't know what to do about it. I tried installing ADO at sp6 specifically on the server, but the server wouldn't have it.

Comment: If the exact same code runs without errors elsewhere, I would suspect IIS more than SQL server, because it's ASP that is reacting differently to a command. Maybe the driver is different; can you check the connectionstring in the location that is working? Is it the same as in this location where it's failing?

Comment: The original server connects via ODBC using windows authentication, and the authentication was linked to AD. My manager wants the connection to be authenticated against an SQL User account. Its very strange though. The app has a number of DB's being used. I have the connection strings for those set in the same way as this one and they too call Stored Procs. Permissions are the same for those. They also call the same generic function. The sp's return the expected records and the disconnection happens as expected. It's just this one SP that I have found so far that is giving this behaviour

Comment: even when creating the ODBC Connection all are using SQL Server as the driver. If I change this to be SQL Server Native Client 11.0. It still gives the same issue

Comment: Hmmm.. I changed my connection string from : `"Provider=SQLNCLI11.1; SERVER=myserver; DATABASE=myDb; UID=myUser; PWD=myPassword;` to also include `Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; Trusted_Connection=yes;"` now I receive  an error stating that the execute permission was denied on the sp for my database on schema dbo. If I go the the properties of the SP against the myUSer Execute has been granted and the Grantor is dbo

Comment: It's likely an ADO provider issue, you can't just mix and match. Different providers have different behaviours.

Comment: I have a feeling the SQLServer users also need to be set up in AD and that perhaps the one for this DB hasn't been set up. Our AD Administrator isn't in today, SO I'll have to check in a couple of days. All ODBC, IIS, SQLServer and Application settings are correct as far as I can tell. It's only AD that I don't have access to/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error centered around dates. In the SP I have dateformat set to DMY. The DB language is set to British English. In the ODBC Connection the Language for SQLSErver Messages was also set to British English. What I Didn't have set was `Use regional settings when outputting currency,numbers, dates and times` in the ODBC Driver, so when returning with the resultset, it was reverting to default settings thus not mapping datetimes correctly and killing the resultset.